# My "lagged consumption" variable accounts for all the variation in my dependent variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, lags

I chose the topic of consumption for my assignment in econometrics. My explanatory variables are interest rate, consumer credit, oil price, disposable income and lagged consumption by 1 year.

Using these variables and conducting a omitted variable Wald test shows that although all the coefficients are positive ,basically all the variation in my dependent variable comes from lagged consumption and makes all my other variables seem useless. Is there any way to fix this or should I just keep it how it is and explain that consumption is more or less completely explained by lagged consumption?

This is my first time doing a econometrics module so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if consumption does not change much, you are essentially regressing a variable on itself and other variables, and since there is no better way to explain something than by itself (statistically speaking - in terms of economics, you learn rather little, of course, from saying that if consumption was high, it also tends to stay so), you get that all the variation gets explained by the lag.

In the extreme case of no change at all, this answer shows that residuals even become identically zero: [OLS coefficients of regressions of fitted values and residuals on the original regressors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500018/ols-coefficients-of-regressions-of-fitted-values-and-residuals-on-the-original-r/500023#500023)

As to what you should do, that will depend on your research question - as the argument above illustrates, your goal should indeed not be to maximize fit, as you can always achieve that by some uninteresting regressor (or a set thereof).

In other words, you need to think about which question you want to answer and which econometric design is suitable to answer that question. To be fair, these are often hard questions!

Comment: Thank you for your input i think i understand